# GoogleAPI - Service Account C# on Godaddy

Tags: c#, google-api, x509certificate2, service-accounts

I'm stuck in a big problem.

I have build a MVC WebAPI in ASP.NET which uses google api (service account) for writing to google spreadsheet. I can run the application very well and also i'm able to write to the spreadsheet. But the problem is when I host it on a godaddy's shared windows server it gives me an error.

---

> [CryptographicException:
>
> An internal error occurred.
>
> ]
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr) +33    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils.
>
> _LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags,
>   Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
>
> +0
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String
>   fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) +218
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.Import(String
>   fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) +33
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import(String
>   fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) +33
>   GAExampleMVC.GoogleAnalytics.GoogleAnalyticsService.GetStats() in
>   d:\Aakash\Thermax\webapi\GAExampleMVC\GAExampleMVC\GoogleAnalytics\GoogleAnalytics.cs:50
>   GAExampleMVC.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in
>   d:\Aakash\Thermax\webapi\GAExampleMVC\GAExampleMVC\Controllers\HomeController.cs:16
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
>   +55    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
>   +21    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +189
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +324
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +105

---

I just don't understand why it isn't working on Godaddy while the same code is working well in localhost.

I guess it is related to some certificate store which is not accessible from my code.

Can anyone please help me knowing the exact issue and how can I solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is older, but I thought I would provide an answer based on my recent experience in case anyone else comes across it.  As far as I am aware, the actual problem is that GoDaddy does not allow changes in the App Pool identity on shared hosting.  To fix the problem at it's root, the "Load User Profile" setting must be set for the App Pool identity. This allows the p12 to be loaded. However, as I stated, this is not an option for shared hosting platforms. So, the workaround...

My inspiration for the solution came from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-dotnet-client/JSILy1UX1rQ).  I have no experience with Bouncy Castle and didn't have time to learn, so this is what I came up with.

First...take the p12 file that Google provides using the Developer Console and convert it to a pk8 private key.  I used OpenSSL to do this.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -nocerts -out key.pem
openssl pkcs8 -in key.pem -topk8 -out p8key.pem
```

Second, save the resulting pk8 key in your application App_Data folder.

Third, read the key from the pk8 file using StreamReader and initialize the ServiceAccountCredential using .FromPrivateKey instead of .FromCertificate.

```
Dim stReader As New System.IO.StreamReader _
(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath & "[PathToPK8File].pk8")
        Dim aLine As String
        Dim keyfile As String
        While True
            aLine = stReader.ReadLine()
            If aLine Is Nothing Then
                keyfile = keyfile & vbCrLf
                Exit While
            Else
                keyfile = keyfile & aLine & " "
            End If
        End While

        Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

        scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly)

        Dim credential As ServiceAccountCredential = New ServiceAccountCredential(
            New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceEmail) With {
            .Scopes = scopes
            }.FromPrivateKey(keyfile)) // Use FromPrivateKey instead of FromCertificate
```

All loads properly on production server.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem with GoDaddy basic hosting. Also, when converting the .pem file to PKCS8, you can use the -nocrypt flag to remove encryption.